# Testing an Angular filter which uses Math outside of the browser

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I've written a simple Angular filter which utilizes `Math` in its implementation. It works when I run the Jasmine spec in the browser, but not when I run it with Chutzpah, since it apparently doesn't define `Math`.

This is the filter:

```
return angular.module('app.filters.ddToDmsFilter', [])
.filter('ddToDms', function () {
    return function (dd) {
        var D = Math.trunc(dd);
        var M = Math.trunc((dd * 60) % 60);
        var S = Math.round((dd * 3600) % 60);
        return D + '°' + M + '′' + S + '″';
    };
});
```

This is the test:

```
define([
    'app',
    'angularAMD',
    'angular-mocks',
    'angular',
    './ddToDmsFilter'
], function () {
    'use strict';

    describe('Filter: ddToDms', function () {

        var ddToDms;

        beforeEach(module('app.filters.ddToDmsFilter'));
        beforeEach(inject(function ($filter) {
            ddToDms = $filter('ddToDms');
        }));

        it('should handle 0', function () {
            expect(ddToDms(0)).toBe('0°0′0″');
        });
    });
});
```

The error output:

```
Test 'Filter: ddToDms:should handle 0' failed
    TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'Math.trunc(dd)') in ...
```

How do I make this test run outside of a browser environment?

Comment: could you add `ddToDms` filter? basically you are not doing operation with filter, you have just created filter object..

Comment: @PankajParkar: I added the implementation.

Comment: why you don't you mock `Math` prototype using `spyOn`?

Comment: @PankajParkar: I don't really see how that would work, seeing as the implementation of `Math` is central to the functionality.

Comment: That is the point. You don't want to test that the implementation of Math.truncate returns the correct values. You want to test that your filter can format the _results_ of the calculation correctly.

Comment: @henrikmerlander: Okay, suppose I do the calculations elsewhere, like a service, and this filter just formats the result from that service... I still have to *test that service too*. I can't get around the fact that I use the `Math` object for calculations. Either way, I've solved the problem and posted my own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `Math.trunc` is not widely supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc

Using the polyfill defined in the link above fixed the problem:

```
Math.trunc = Math.trunc || function (x) {
    return x < 0 ? Math.ceil(x) : Math.floor(x);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could inject a service that uses the Math function. Then you can mock the service in the test to get rid of the explicit Math call.

Comment: I've added the implementation of the filter now. As you can see, the implementation of `Math` is pretty central to the functionality, so I don't think I can realistically stub it in any useful way.

Comment: I think your filter has too many responibilities. It both does some calculation by using the Math function, and also formats the result to the desired output format. What you are really doing here is testing that the Math function behaves correctly rather than testing that your filter formats the output correctly. This makes the filter rather hard to test.

Comment: I'm just using `Math` to do calculations which is what defines the equation. I could split this up into separate parts, but that's beside the point, I'll still have to use `Math`.